# React Native Expo removeEventListener fails "sometimes"

Tags: react-native, expo, event-listener

```
useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
    return () => {
      // in order to avoid error on saving while dev stage
      try {
        AppState.removeEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
      } catch {
        (e) => console.log("error useEffect cleanup ", e);
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

I have no clue.. ..but it seldom go to catch and so, a lot of listeners stay alive... :(  ...and it doesnt retrieve the error..

I have added the Try/Catch because without it, each time I was modify something in my code it would go to an error before applying the changes... :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback method which comes from AppState.addEventListener() to remove the listener in the return block.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const appState = AppState.addEventListener('change', () => {
      const state = AppState.currentState;
    });

    return appState.remove;
},[])
```

Comment: Does this actually work?  It doesn't seem to for me.  I even copy the example straight from docs and it is just adding more and more listeners.